Date-fns display dates/amount of days question
What's the best solution to display Today/Yesterday/X days ago?
Currently my code is:
const { differenceInDays, differenceInHours, startOfDay, addDays } = window.dateFns;

const transactions = [
  { amount: 200, date: new Date('2024-07-16T23:59:17.178Z') },
  { amount: 455.23, date: new Date('2024-07-16T07:42:02.383Z') },
  { amount: -306.5, date: new Date('2024-07-15T09:15:04.904Z') },
  { amount: 25000, date: new Date('2024-07-14T10:17:24.185Z') },
  { amount: -642.21, date: new Date('2024-07-15T00:01:59.604Z') },
  { amount: -133.9, date: new Date('2024-07-15T23:59:17.194Z') },
  { amount: 79.97, date: new Date('2024-07-16T00:01:17.929Z') },
  { amount: 1300, date: new Date('2024-07-16T23:59:36.790Z') }
];

const container = document.getElementById('transactions');

function formatTransactionDate(date) {
  const now = new Date('2024-07-17T00:01:17.178Z');
  const startOfToday = startOfDay(now);
  const startOfYesterday = startOfDay(addDays(now, -1));

  if (date >= startOfToday && date <= now) {
    return "Today";
  } else if (date >= startOfYesterday && date < startOfToday) {
    return "Yesterday";
  } else {
    const daysPassed = differenceInDays(now, date);
    return `${daysPassed} days ago`;
  }
}

function displayTransactions() {
  transactions.forEach(transaction => {
    const formattedDate = formatTransactionDate(transaction.date);
    const transactionElement = document.createElement('div');
    transactionElement.classList.add('transaction');
    transactionElement.innerHTML = `
      <span>Amount:</span> ${transaction.amount.toFixed(2)}<br>
      <span>Date:</span> ${formattedDate}<br>
    `;
    container.appendChild(transactionElement);
  });
}

// Display transactions on page load
displayTransactions();

But the thing is that if we compare 17/07/2024 00:01 to 16/07/2024 23:59 - it's showing as Today.
Also if we compare 17/07/2024 23:59 and 16/07/2024 00:01 - it should count as 1 day?
What's the best way for let's say banking app to advice if it was today/yesterday or X amount of days exactly? How is it usually done in the banking apps?
Have tried the code above but still having an issue.

You need to compare with equivalent time to get desired result, make the time 00:00 or 23:59 for both and then compare no matter if it's reached or not.

I highly suggest that you use formatRelative instead. See documentation here. You can combine it with formatDistance as well.
Here's your example, and how to override the default messages per English/US locale:
import { formatRelative, formatDistance, differenceInDays, subDays } from 'date-fns';
import { enUS } from 'date-fns/locale';

const customLocale = {
  ...enUS,
  formatRelative: (token, date, baseDate, options) => {
    const formatRelativeLocale = {
      lastWeek: "'Last' eeee 'at' p",
      yesterday: "'Yesterday at' p",
      today: "'Today at' p",
      tomorrow: "'Tomorrow at' p",
      nextWeek: "'Next' eeee 'at' p",
      other: 'P',
    };

    return formatRelativeLocale[token];
  },
};

function formatTransactionDate(date) {
    const now = new Date();
    const distance = Math.abs(differenceInDays(date, now))
    if (distance >= 7)
         return formatDistance(date, now, {addSuffix: true})
    return formatRelative(date, now, { locale: customLocale });
}


console.log(formatTransactionDate(new Date()));  // Today at 2:30 PM
console.log(formatTransactionDate(subDays(new Date(), 1)));  // Yesterday at 2:30 PM
console.log(formatTransactionDate(subDays(new Date(), 3)));  // Last Monday at 2:30 PM
console.log(formatTransactionDate(subDays(new Date(), 7)));  // 7 days ago
console.log(formatTransactionDate(subDays(new Date(), 30)));  // about 1 month ago

